yfinance not returning yesterday data
Yfinance doesnt return yesterday data
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

def get_last_two_days_ohlc(ticker):
    # Fetch historical data for the last 5 days to ensure we get at least two closed days
    data = yf.download(ticker, period="5d")
    
    # Drop rows with missing data
    data.dropna(inplace=True)
    
    # Get the last two closed days
    last_two_days = data.iloc[-2:]
    
    # Return the OHLC data
    return last_two_days[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]

# Example usage
ticker = "EURUSD=X"
ohlc_data = get_last_two_days_ohlc(ticker)
print(ohlc_data)


This is the result
    [*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
                Open      High       Low     Close
         Date                                              
  2024-08-29  1.112496  1.114020  1.105632  1.112496
  2024-08-30  1.108045  1.109570  1.105400  1.108045
  2024-09-02  1.104484  1.107763  1.104252  1.104484
  2024-09-04  1.104606  1.106562  1.104240  1.105583

I've tried running different symbols but its happening with all of them.

You're getting the correct data.
Because of Labor day in America, Exchange was closed.
List of Holidays: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stock-market-holiday-schedule
Y-Finance Official site Data is not available for 9/3/2024.
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURUSD=X/history/


But as far as I can see the holiday was on 2 September and data from 3 September is missing or have I misunderstood something and it works differently.

The data gives the information for the 2 September but not the 3 September. Plus the symbol used to check was the EURUSD, which should not have been closed or am i wrong on that. I'm aware the stock markets were closed by were FOREX markets closed as well?

you're welcome!

Holiday or not, history is supposed to get last 5 trading days data. It is a bug in yahoo finance API.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
